# Javascript: Return sliced elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, axios, slice

I have used the .slice() function within my code to slice an array of 10 elements that I get from the response of an API request (.get), this allows me to show 9 out of the 10.

But, I would like to return the 10th element when I click on a button.

For example, if the API request has a total of 19 elements and I am slicing them like (0, 9), then after clicking on a button it should add the 10th element to next 9 and so on.

Below is the Javascript code that I am using:

```
getProjects: function() {
      this.loading = true;

      let url = this.craftURL();

      axios.get(url, {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json"
        }
      }).then(response => {
        this.loading = false;
        console.log("Response", response.data)

        if (response.data.projects) {
          response.data.projects.project.slice(0, 9).forEach(project => {
            this.projects.push(this.parseProject(project));
          });
        } else if (response.data.search.response) {
          if (response.data.search.response.numberFound == 0) {
            this.noProjects = true;
            return;
          }

          response.data.search.response.projects.project.slice(0, 9).forEach(project => {
            this.projects.push(this.parseProject(project));
          });

          if (this.projects.length == response.data.search.response.numberFound) {
            this.hideButton = true;
            return;
          } else {
            this.hideButton = false;
            return;
          }
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    },
```

this.projects is an empty array that I have added within the data.

Many thanks!

Comment: it seems that your `getProjects` function should return a `Promise` itself, you can not return from a `Promise` inside a normal function. because Promises are asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand, you want to implement pagination to reduce the load. You can set skip and limit and get desired amount of data. Kindly refer to the documentation for skip and limit for idea.

```
 loadMore() {
     this.data = {
          user:this.username,
          skip: this.s+=1,
          limit: this.l+=1
        }
    this.service.getabcd(data).subscribe(x=>{
    this.project=x;
}
```

And in backend you set limit and skip like this

```
router.post('/abcs/', async (req, res) => {
    const ab= await XYZ.find({ username: req.body['user'] 
     }).skip(req.body.skip).limit(req.body.limit);       
    res.json(ab);
});
```